# How do I lazy load Angular 2 components protocol relatively?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, protocol-relative

I am attempting to lazy load a component in angular 2, but I get a mixed content error.  My application is running in https, but the component is being loaded over http.  Is there a way to force a protocol relative load?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm also facing the same issue.